# How do I interpret a Scatter Plot of probabilities?

Tags: statistics, visualization, interpretation

Help me with interpretation of the following scatter plot[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.